# Crontab run Wget command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wget, cron

Im using a crontab like:

```
00 */1 * * * wget http://www.test.com/cron/archieve
```

I would like to know the difference using `> /dev/null 2>&1` in the end of the command, and if its recomended.

Comment: `> /dev/null 2>&1` just silences the output. I have no idea what this does when run with cron, though.

Comment: I rather suggest to redirect both standard output & error to some given file, e.g. `> wget.out 2>&1` then you could look into `wget.out` if you suspect some issue

Comment: Maybe append rather than overwrite, though; otherwise the next run will truncate the file, possibly before you get a chance to examine it. This will require you to set up some log rotation, though. Better IMHO to run `wget` in silent mode (`-q` option; error output only) and allow `cron` to send you email when there is something to report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not add `> /dev/null 2>&1`, output of that command will be mailed to user that this cron job runs at - probably you.

I would imagine you don't want to be spammed by cron jobs - but this is up to you

**EDIT**: explanation what `> /dev/null 2>&1` really means.

There are 3 standard file descriptors: 0 (stdin), 1 (stdout) and 2 (stderr).
`> file` is the same as `1> file`, in other words, redirect std. file descriptor 1 (stdout) to file.

`2>&1` means redirect std. file descriptor 2 (stderr) to the same place where 1 (stdout) is redirected.

In the end, full effect of `> /dev/null 2>&1` means redirect both stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`, in other words make that program completely silent

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Should I use `wget` with `-O /dev/null` too?

Comment: I guess you can, but that means you are saving output of `wget` into `/dev/null`. If that's the case, why having `wget` line in cron in first place? It would not do anything then, would it? Or do you want to issue `GET` request just to show that your server is alive?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect stdio/stderr streams in `> /dev/null 2>&1` if the result doesn't matter for you. See some example:

```
alex@work:~/dev$ ls
arm-2011.03-42-arm-none-eabi.bin  linux
backup_from_ak                    linux-3.4.6.tar.bz2
bc-1.06                           linux.tar.gz                 
CodeSourcery                      mach-lpc32xx                               
alex@work:~/dev$ ls > /dev/null 2>&1
alex@work:~/dev$
```